# iplot strange connected Y-Axis

Tags: python, plotly

When I run de command:

```
iplot(df_final[['ds', 'yhat']].set_index('ds').to_iplot())
```

It plots the following chart:

[image]

What is this strange weird connection among the observations?

A close look is:

[image]

When I don't use `iplot` it is correct:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate the plots in iplot() with the connecting lines by adding duplicate dates. One solution to get rid of those lines was sorting the dataframe by x-axis i.e. dates (here 'ds' column) before ploting.

```
# Creating sample data
ds = pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=100).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(ds, columns=['ds'])
df['yhat'] = np.sin(30*3.14/180)*np.random.randn(100)
df.iplot(x='ds', y='yhat')
# plot link below
```

[Plot without duplicate dates using iplot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCuti.png)

```
# Create duplicate dates and adding it to the dataframe
df2 = df.append(df.sample(n=5, replace=False)) # this line creates 5 duplicate rows
df2[['ds', 'yhat']].iplot(x='ds', y='yhat')
# plot link below
```

[Plot with duplicate dates and connecting lines using iplot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88WoM.png)

```
# Same plot with plot() works just fine
df2.plot(x='ds', y='yhat')
# plot link below
```

[Plot with duplicate dates using plot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cpdo.png)

```
# Possible solution:
# Sort by date column
df2 = df2.sort_values(by='ds', ascending=True)
# Plot with sorted values
df2[['ds', 'yhat']].iplot(x='ds', y='yhat')
# plot link below
```

[Plot with sorted date column with duplicate dates using iplot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlx6M.png)